# Compute timeseries in a streaming way using input time-series from disparates sources

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, time-series, stream-processing

I develop and maintain a web app that displays metrics data.
Theses metrics are mainly time series with a regular resolution coming from
sensors, programmable logic controllers etc. Some of theses times series are
measures (like temperature etc.) and some others are the result of a compute
using others time-series as inputs. The measures come from distincts sources
with differents formats,protocols and delay of availability. They are all batch oriented for
now but stream oriented will coming soon.

For now Importation of data is done using Apache Camel that stores data into a
database. The compute of metrics is then done by a "homemade" batch program
that is called by apache Camel each time a batch import is done, giving to this script the start and end date of the imported time-series and some kind of namespace to process only time-series that are concerned by the batch.

While this solution works for now, it has drawbacks due its batch orientation. I'm starting to think about a better solution for future improvments.

To be more precise i need a system that is able to generate output time-series
by applying mathematical operations on inputs time-series, things as simple as

```
tsout = (t1+t2) / t3
```

considering inputs (t1, t2, t3) are not available at the same time because
they come from distincts sources (some from batch, some from streams..). Some
computed time-series are used as input of some others. All of theses create
a dependency graph.

Are there some design patterns, tools, frameworks or even "concepts" that
could help me to improve the generation/computing of metrics in a more
"streaming" way as the data is coming, abstrating disparate sources and
considering the dependencies ?

I took a look at frameworks like apache Kafka, Flink, Spark.. but i doubt they
really answer my needs. They allows to do `stream / event processing` but i'm 
not sure this refers to the same kind of processing i need to do.

Hope my question is sufficiently clear, it is not easy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Is this information not available in the database?
Something like the row creation / update / ... time. You then would have all data available already and can customize and compare based on the various fields you have.